# Resolution independent SWT Dialog

Tags: java, dialog, swt, screen-resolution

Can somebody tell me how to achieve resolution independence for size and appearance of swt dialogs. my dialog works correct in 1680x1050, but when resolution is changed to 1280x800, part of dialog is clipped away!

Comment: You can either wrap you content in a [`ScrolledComposite`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html) or try setting the size of the dialog manually by using the `heightHint` of the layout data.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use absolute coordinates, take a look at layouts instead. `GridLayout` I believe is the easiest to use.

See [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) article.